# Could not start backup:Request failed with status code 400 Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I'm trying to create a backup system for Firestore.
I followed every step of this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) and when I tried to deploy the code, it returned `Request failed with status code 400`

PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com permissions: Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin,
Editor,
Storage Admin

This is the code of app.js

```
'use strict';


const axios = require('axios');
const dateformat = require('dateformat');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');
const util = require('util')
const request = require('request');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

const db = admin.firestore();

const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'AIza*****',
  Promise: Promise
});

const app = express();

// Trigger a backup
app.get('/cloud-firestore-export', async (req, res) => {
  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore'],
  });

  const accessTokenResponse = await auth.getAccessToken();
  const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.token;

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
  };

  const { outputUriPrefix } = req.query;
  if (!outputUriPrefix) {
    res.status(500).send('outputUriPrefix required');
  } else if (outputUriPrefix && outputUriPrefix.indexOf('gs://') !== 0) {
    res.status(500).send('Malformed outputUriPrefix: ${outputUriPrefix}');
  }

  // Construct a backup path folder based on the timestamp
  const timestamp = dateformat(Date.now(), 'yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM-ss');
  let path = outputUriPrefix;
  if (path.endsWith('/')) {
    path += timestamp;
  } else {
    path += '/' + timestamp;
  }

  const body = {
    outputUriPrefix: path,
  };

  // If specified, mark specific collections for backup
  const { collections } = req.query;
  if (collections) {
    body.collectionIds = collections.split(',');
  }

  const projectId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT;
  const url = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/' + projectId + '/databases/(default):exportDocuments';

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, body, { headers });
    res
      .status(200)
      .send(response.data)
      .end();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response) {
      console.warn(e.response.data);
    }

    res
      .status(500)
      .send('Could not start backup:' + e.message)
      .end();
  }
});


°°°°
// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('App listening on port ${PORT}');
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});
```

I have another function that is listening to '/'. Is possible that this can cause the problem?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "solution-scheduled-backups",
   "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Scheduled Cloud Firestore backups via AppEngine cron",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy --quiet app.yaml cron.yaml",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Google, Inc.",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.2.1",
    "@google/maps": "^0.5.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.4.0",
    "googleapis": "^42.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  }
}
```

I also look inside Cron log and there is nothing related to the error. It only returns `500 error`

Comment: Hello Matteo,

I'm looking at the differences between your code and the guide you are following, for the time being i'm seeing that you are not defining the constants at the top of your app.js as they are done in the guide, i also see that you do not actually start the server.

Do you actually have these details in your app.js or did you forgot to add them/removed them by need?

Comment: @dhauptman Yes this is because I have another function. I updated the code please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main problem is the bucket location

When you create a backup bucket you must use `Multi-Region` or you will receive a deny from the server.

I think this is a bug of Google Cloud

> Solution

Delete the bucket and create a new one with a Multi-Regional location

The error with Single Location:

```
'Bucket backup-bucket is in location EUR4. This project can only operate on buckets 
spanning location europe-north1 or europe-west1 or eu or europe-west2 or 
europe-west3 or europe-west4 or europe-west5 or europe-west6.',
```

Answer (score 0):

So i've been replicating your issue and i've found the solution.

I kept getting the same error as you and I finally managed to figure it out. If you look into GAE logs you can see the error saying that 'Project \' "YOUR PROJECT"   \' is not a Cloud Firestore enabled project.'.

This worked for me:

1. Make a new project.
2. Go to API Library in GCP and enable Firestore Installation API.
3. Go to [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) and link your GCP project to a firebase project.
4. Go to database and create Firestore Database.
5. Follow the repo with the permissions and the deployment to app engine.
6. Test the cron and it will be successful.

If you ever had DataStore enabled in your actual project you will not be able to do a Firestore instance at step 3.

This will create you the needed buckets with the .appspot.com format, that you have give permissions to.

Go to GAE and create your cron.yaml, app.js and everything else you need. I used [this repo](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/tree/master/firestore/solution-scheduled-backups) for tests.

In the readme.md of the repo you have the exact commands that you have to do in order to give permissions to your service account.

Remember to change the bucket as told in cron.yaml.

Follow the steps mentioned in the repo as they are pretty well done.

Let me know if it worked for you!