# Error with GCP Dual Region storage bucket

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have set my storage bucket as dual region NAM4 (US-CENTRAL1 and US-EAST1) https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations#location-dr while I have my cloud functions and everything else on us-east-1.  When running a backup from a cloud function to this dual region bucket I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Bucket myapp-prod-backup.wekasolutions.co.nz is in location NAM4. This project can only operate on buckets spanning location us-east1 or us.
    at Gaxios._request (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js
```

I'm guessing it will work if I use a us-east1 bucket but is there any way I can use a dual region bucket like this?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890923/12857703) you need to use `Multi-Region` buckets for backups.

So in order to fix it you are going to have to create a new bucket in one of the multi regions described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations#location-mr), since you have your dual region as `NAM4` you can replace it with a `US Multi-Region` Bucket.

Comment: This solves the problem as I expected it would.  So it is just a bug with GCP then?  I chose dual region as I assumed it would be cheaper than multi region as I would not get charged transfer costs if it was in the same region us-east1 (which is one of the regions in NAM4).

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug or an expected behaviour that is not described in the documentation to be honest. I would say that in order to find that out you open a [Bug Report on Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0) so that the engineering team can confirm that.